# resizeMode contain showing space before and after image in react native

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, height, width

I'm trying to show an image whose width adjust according to height I'm using resizeMode="contain" for this purpose but it shows space before and after image. I tried setting margin, padding, left, right but none of them worked.

[image]

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <ScrollView horizontal>
        <View style={{ borderColor: "#f00", borderWidth: 2, height: 300 }}>
            <Image source={images[0].uri} resizeMode="contain" style={{ height: 300, width: 300 }} />
        </View>
        <View style={{ borderColor: "#f00", borderWidth: 2, height: 300 }}>
            <Image source={images[1].uri} resizeMode="contain" style={{ height: 300 }} />
        </View>
   </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

`resizeMode="contain"` is `Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view`, and it means ( on your image ), stretch height and width until the `height=300` but keep the aspect ratio. So the width will never cover the screen because it's smaller than height.

If you want the width cover all screen, use `stretch` or `cover`.

Maybe I don't understand your question correct. If it is, let me know and I delete my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As `resizeMode="contain"` scale the image evenly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) also set the width aspect ratio equivalent to the height you want to give the image.

For example, if you have an image of **210x300** and you want your image to have a height of **100**. You need to set the width to ***the same aspect ratio*** as **70**.
`<Image style={{height:100, width:70, resizeMode:"contain"}}/>`

Otherwise, you will get a width spacing of the original aspect ratio of the image.